# Unused output parameters

Tags: c, pointers

When a C function returns values by reference, am I required to pass a valid pointer to the function for output values that I do not need? For example take the function:
`max_f32(float32_t *x, float32_t *val, size_t *i);` where `val` and `i` are return values but I only care about the result `val`.

Am I required to pass a valid pointer to the parameter `i`, or can I pass some kind of dummy pointer or `NULL`? Does C have a mechanism for handling this kind of thing? Python, for example, can return to `_` in this situation.

I realize that it is not terribly burdensome to allocate a variable for `i` and that the compiler will optimize it out. But I would like to understand this part of the C language better.

Comment: Since C99 you can write `&(size_t){0}` for a pointer to dummy value, instead of declaring a named variable

Comment: I would also consider making a wrapper  (either inline function, or preprocessor macro) that takes the two arguments and expresses what you are trying to do, this will make the code easier to read

Comment: @M.M This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Clearly, however, it does not improve code readability to use `&(size_t){0}`.

Comment: "Am I required to pass a valid pointer to the parameter i, or can I pass some kind of dummy pointer or NULL?"  If the function is ready for the `NULL`, then yes.  Example: review `long strtol(const char * nptr, char ** endptr, int base);` and how `endptr` may be `NULL`, but not `nptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call the function with 3 parameters, because the function expects 3 parameters. There's no language-level mechanism to omit `i`.
It's all about how the function has been documented and implemented to deal with `i`.
It may or may not be OK to pass `NULL`.

Assume you must pass valid `i`, unless it's explicitly documented that passing `NULL` is OK.

Consider the following two implementations, first requiring valid `i`, the second making `i` optional through the use of `NULL`.

```
void max_f32_required(float32_t *x, float32_t *val, size_t *i) {
    *val = *x;
    *i = 42;
}

// Expect to find it documented that i is ignored when NULL.
void max_f32_optional(float32_t *x, float32_t *val, size_t *i) {
    *val = *x;
    if (i != NULL) *i = 42; // Omitted if i is NULL.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is up to the creator of the function;  They may choose to allow NULL for unused pointers, or may choose to *require* that a valid pointer is passed.

Hopefully, they also include enough documentation to make clear if each parameter is required to be valid, or may be NULL instead.

Comment: Is it wrong to allow a function to write to a NULL pointer if this is not a documented feature? I have heard conflicting advice on whether it is safe to write to a NULL pointer.

Comment: @Mike It is completely unsafe

Comment: "Unsafe" is pretty kind.... although it is Undefined Behavior, and technically anything *could* happen, it is almost universally *guaranteed* to crash the program.

Comment: @abelenky: You should not write that technically anything can happen when that is technically false. When the C standard says something has “undefined behavior,” that only means the C standard does not impose any requirements on the behavior. It does not, and cannot, nullify other requirements, such as rules imposed by the operating system, the hardware, consumer product safety laws, and more. So, no, it is not technically true that anything can happen. For example, attempting to access via a null pointer cannot cause your process to read another process’ memory in violation of OS safeguards.

Comment: @EricPostpischil All those other things you listed can be nullified. For example one possible result is that the UB causes the CPU clock multiplier to be overwritten , the computer catches on fire, the building burns down.  I cannot understand why you go off onto this wall of text whenever anyone makes the simple and clear statement that anything could happen.

Comment: @M.M: Writing via a null pointer does not overwrite the CPU clock multiplier in general-purpose multiuser operating systems, since they have protections against that. The reason I oppose that false statement is that it promotes a misunderstanding of the C standard. Some undefined behaviors are deliberately used to provide extensions, which is one of the things the C standard was designed to accommodate. Such an extension **requires** that the rules of its C implementation apply. If the meaning of “undefined behavior” were that “anything can happen,” then no such extension could be defined.

Comment: ***Within The C Standard*** anything can happen, including Nasal Demons.  ***Within a particular compiler implementation*** certain extensions can exist.  ***Within a particular operating system*** certain guarantees about process isolation and hardware protection may exist. But the C Standard still goes with ***anything***.